# Speex or nellymoser

Tags: apache-flex, flash, audio, flash-media-server, codec

I am developing a voice application, I have 2 options speex and nellymoser .Why should I use speex instead of nellymoser in flex application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should make it clear , Comparison of both codecs for flex: 
http://askmeflash.com/article/2/speex-vs-nellymoser

Comment: In summary, you will save bandwidth if you use Speex in almost every case. Speex is also a open source codec whereas Nelly is not.

Answer (score 0):

Speex is open source, optimized for speech and seems to have lower bandwidth requirements. However, in Flash/AIR, Speex is always 16 kHz, which is not quite the Skype-like crispness of the sound. Because of that, we're currently contemplating switching to the "old" Nellymoser where we have an option of 22 and even 44 kHz.