# Enforce Codec to Speex (instead of Nellymoser)

Tags: actionscript-3, audio-streaming, flash

We have written a web based discussion forum using Flash and RTMP for streaming and recording. As has been discussed multiple times on the net (for example on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750824/speex-or-nellymoser), there are multiple codecs available for such a task. Primarily these codecs are Speex and Nellymoser, whilst Speex is a clear favourite for multiple reasons.

In our application, we have explicitly set Speex as the codec to be chosen:

```
    mic = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();
    mic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
```

This works, mostly. However, sometimes a user comes along and streams using Nellymoser for no reason that I can see. The last user was on OSX 10.8, current Chrome or Firefox with current Flash. That is a setup that we have used already hundreds of times from different machines. There must be a variable that I'm not seeing.

How do I enforce the codec to Speex? We need to ban Nellymoser for good, since it produces many problems (bad compression, not properly mergeable with Speex streams, often corrupt streams, ...).

For completeness (maybe there's a side-effect that I'm not seeing), I'm publishing the code surrounding the two lines above:

```
    var options:MicrophoneEnhancedOptions = new MicrophoneEnhancedOptions();
    options.mode = MicrophoneEnhancedMode.FULL_DUPLEX;
    options.autoGain = false;
    options.echoPath = 128;
    options.nonLinearProcessing = true;
    mic = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();
    mic.setSilenceLevel(0, 2000);
    mic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
    mic.encodeQuality = 7;
    mic.framesPerPacket = 1;
    mic.gain = 50;
    mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);  
    var ns: NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
    ns.attachAudio(mic);
    ns.publish(stream, "live");
    netStreams.push(ns);
```

Comment: Think it's possible they're using FP <10 where SPEEX isn't available?

Comment: @JKillian That was one of my initial guesses. We are requiring FP 11.2 since then(newest version available to Linux). It might have improved the situation, but the last user I saw had Chrome 36 and FP 14.

Comment: Hmm, tough question then. Guessing you can't make out any trend in the platforms/browsers where the problems occur?

Comment: @JKillian unfortunately no. I thought it would be older Windows machines with outdated FP versions, but now this Mac user with brand new Chrome/Firefox and FP came along to destroy my hopes^^